# Prove: $T=\{u\subseteq X:u^C finite\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let there be $X$ and let $T=\{u\subseteq X:u^C finite\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$

Prove $T$ is a topology:

1. $\emptyset \in T$ and $X\subseteq X$ where $X^C=\emptyset$ is finite so $X\in T$
2. let $u_\alpha\in T$ we have to prove that $\cup_{\alpha\in I}u_\alpha\in T$, how can it be done?
3. let $u_i\in T$ we have to prove that $\cap_{1\leq i \leq n}u_i\in T$ so $\cap_{1\leq i \leq n}u_i=(\cup_{1\leq i \leq n}u^C_i)^C$ is it correct?

Comment: For 2) note that the complement of a union is a subset of a complement of any of the sets. A subset of a finite set has to be?

Comment: Note:  $T$ is the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology)

Comment: @Sorfosh So $$(\bigcap u_{\alpha})^C=\bigcup u_{\alpha}^C$$, but $u_{\alpha})^C$ so $$(\bigcap u_{\alpha})^C$$ is finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) Discern two cases:

- $u_{\alpha}=\varnothing$ for every $\alpha\in I$
- some $\alpha_0$ exists with $\alpha_0\neq\varnothing$

First bullet: $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}u_{\alpha}=\varnothing\in T$.

Second bullet: $(\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}u_{\alpha})^{\complement}\subseteq u_{\alpha_0}^{\complement}$ so the complement of the union is - as a subset of a finite set - finite itself.

3) Not correct.

If the intersection is empty then we are ready. If not then:

$(\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq n}u_i)^{\complement}=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}u_i^{\complement}$ which is - as a finite union of finite sets - finite itself.